# Finding the earliest date in list of custom date objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, object

Given a list of date objects I need to find the date that comes earliest in a file

I have written the following code to do this:

```
return min(dates, key=lambda x: x.year)
```

Each object has a year, month, and day attribute.
**I must use a custom class which I have created (at bottom of post)**

This code works until there are two dates with the same year. If two dates have the same year it returns which one comes first in the list which is not what is expected.

For example, these two dates:

```
1988 10 10
1988 09 03
```

The function should return 1988 09 03 but instead it returns 1988 10 10 as it comes first.

How do I compare multiple values of an object in python?

**I have also tried this**

```
return min(min(min(dates, key=lambda x: x.year), key=lambda x: x.month), key=lambda x: x.day)
```

**but it doesn't seem to work**

**I have also tried**

```
return min(dates)
```

but this simply returns the last date in the list

sample of dates file:

```
1954 10 04
1987 12 20
1993 3 10
1996 7 29
1994 5 30
1993 6 9
1989 12 21
2001 6 30
1995 6 14
2002 2 28
1988 6 21
```

```
class Date(object):
    def __init__(self, year, month=1, day=1):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}/{}/{}'.format(self.year, self.month, self.day)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.year, self.month, self.day) < (other.year, other.month, other.day)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return (self.year, self.month, self.day) > (other.year, other.month, other.day)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.year, self.month, self.day) == (other.year, other.month, other.day)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return (self.year, self.month. self.day) <= (other.year, other.month, other.day)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return (self.year, self.month, self.day) >= (other.year, other.month, other.day)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return (self.year, self.month, self.day) != (other.year, other.month, other.day)
```

Parsing:

```
def parse_dates(content):
    dates = []
    for line in content:
        line_date = line.strip().split()
        dates.append(Date(line_date[0], line_date[1], line_date[2]))

    return dates
```

**The file is simply opened and then passed through this which returns a list of date objects**

Then, it is passed into this to return the earliest date:

```
def find_earliest(dates):
    return min(dates)
The file where the dates are retrieved from is shown above
```

**Solved**
I hadn't casted the dates to an int so they stayed as strings, thus the program was comparing strings not actual number values. I simply casted everything to an int then created the date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't cast to `int` in your `Date` constructor, you need to do it in your parsing:

```py
def parse_dates(content):
    dates = []
    for line in content:
        line_date = line.strip().split()
        dates.append(Date(*map(int, line_date)))

    return dates
```

or as a one-liner:

```py
def parse_dates(content):
    return [Date(*map(int, line.strip().split())) for line in content]
```

If you don't want to define all the dunder comparsion methods, you can use [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering):

```py
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Date(object):
    def __init__(self, year, month=1, day=1):
        #cast your values to ints
        self.year  = int(year)
        self.month = int(month)
        self.day   = int(day)

    def __str__(self):
        # using f-string and padding
        # to get "1994/02/07" instead of "1994/2/7"
        return f'{self.year}/{self.month:02}/{self.day:02}'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.year  == other.year
           and self.month == other.month
           and self.day   == other.day

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # works because `or` short-circuits on first True
        return self.year  < other.year
            or self.month < other.month
            or self.day   < other.day
```

Comment: `return (self.year, self.month, self.day) < (other.year, other.month, other.day)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght does that short-circuit as well?

Comment: @Olvin Same for `==` as well

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp, what do you mean?

Comment: @OlvinRoght if `self.year < other.year` mine returns `True` immediately without comparing `self.month < other.month` or `self.day < other.day` (called operator short-circuiting) -- does that hold for tuple-comparison as well? (Honest question; I don't know.)

Comment: It uses lexographical ordering ([proof](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons)), so answer is yes. Your option will have better performance though as it doesn't initialize tuples.

Comment: I should say that **to solve this particular problem** *(find minimum value in the list using built-in [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min))* you don't need `total_ordering` decorator, but it definitely worth mentioning.

Comment: @OlvinRoght yes - if this is an assignment for object use, likely decorators and using them is something they haven't covered yet lol.

Comment: `set(int)` will always fail, perhaps you want `isinstance`, also there is no point in doing a check _after_ you cast all the elements to int in the previous line if it get to that point then it already succeeded otherwise it already failed...

Comment: @Copperfield I know, I know. Really the casts ought to be in a `try... except ValueError` block

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp yes - a lot simpler just to wrap it in a try/except!  ...especially because the type checking comes after you've actually tried to do a cast, and so you'd still have an exception thrown earlier.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp, if you don't want to define some custom error message, there's no reason to do anything at all as `int()` will throw `ValueError` itself.